# Uniqueness of isom $[・]:R \cong End(R)$ which satisfies $[α]^*=αω,α\in R$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

According to Silverman's ''Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'',

> Proposition 1.1 Let $E/ \Bbb{C}$ be an elliptic curve with complex
> multiplication over ring $R⊂\Bbb{C}$. isom $[・]:R \cong End(R)$ which
> satisfies $[α]^*=αω,α\in R$ exists and **unique**.

Silverman proves existence by using isom $E_Λ\cong \Bbb{C}$.
But I'm stuck with proving **uniqueness**. From $[α]^*=αω$, $[β]^*=βω$, how can I prove $α=β$ ?

Comment: I feel like you got it wrong. You don't have to show that $\alpha$ is unique, but that the map sending $\alpha$ to $[\alpha]$ is unique with the property that it pulls back the invariant differentials nicely. But this is immediate, as we know that on $E \cong \Bbb C / \Lambda$, the morphism $[\alpha]$ takes the form $z \mapsto \alpha z$.

Comment: Just to add to Lurchi's comment, as this question has been bountied. Uniqueness is exactly the following: Let $f,g:R\to \text{End}(E)$ be two isomorphisms such that 

$$f^*(\alpha)\omega =\alpha\omega = g^*(\alpha)\omega$$

for every invariant differential $\omega$. Then $f=g$. 

Can you see now how it follows from what Lurchi wrote (and what Silverman refers to in AEC III §1, Table 1.2) ?